# Como carregar um valor em uma DIV após selecionar uma opção no dropdownlist de um input text que utiliza TypeAhead e Ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, typeahead

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde estou utilizando o plugin [Bootstrap Twitter-TypeAhead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) onde carrego valores dentro de uma input text. A página que estou desenvolvendo possui 2 campos:

**1.** Um campo input text cujo id é "**#produtos**" e que carrega valores de uma coluna no MySql;

**2.** E uma div cujo id é "**#imagem**" e que no caso gostaria que dentro dessa div aparecesse um valor relacionado a opção selecionada no input text.

Tentei encontrar algumas questões similares a minha dúvida porém não consegui achar uma maneira correta de fazer isso:

1. [Carregar valor em input text depois de selecionar valor em select Codeigniter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141073/carregar-valor-em-input-text-depois-de-selecionar-valor-em-select-codeigniter)
2. [ao selecionar um valor de um select, aparecer uma div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178871/ao-selecionar-um-valor-de-um-select-aparecer-uma-div)
3. [Carregar input text após selecionar select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310727/carregar-input-text-ap%c3%b3s-selecionar-select)

Primeiramente, segue a estrutura da minha tabela (**produtos**) no MySql:

```
id | nomeProduto    | categoriaFK | imagem
---------------------------------------------
01 | Tenis Nike     | 1           | 001
02 | Camisa Adidas  | 2           | 002
03 | Sapato Kildare | 1           | 003
```

*Obs: A coluna "categoriaFK" é uma foreing Key dentro da tabela "produtos"*

Abaixo segue o código html que exibe o campo input "**#produtos**" e a div "**#imagem**":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
</head>
 
<body>
<br/>
  <div class="container">
   <h2 align="center">Typeahead with Ajax PHP</h2>
   <br/>
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-4">
   <label>Produto</label>
   <input type="text" name="produtos" id="produtos" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4">
   <label>Imagem</label>
   <div id="imagem" name="imagem"></div>
   
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Abaixo, o código Ajax script que envia uma request para o código php (**fetch.php**):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#produtos').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  },
  afterSelect: function (data) {

      $('#imagem').html(data);
         
    },    
 });
 
});
</script>
```

Abaixo, o código php que envia o resultado da requisição para o Ajax:

```php
<?php
//fetch.php
include 'dbConfig.php';
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nomeProduto LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["nomeProduto"];
  $data[] = $row["imagem"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Como podem observar no código acima, eu inseri dentro do typeahead script um código que executa depois que o valor é selecionado dentro do input text **#produtos** conforme abaixo:

```
afterSelect: function (data) {

      $('#imagem').html(data);
         
    },
```

Nesse caso toda vez que seleciono um valor dentro do input text ele mostra esse mesmo valor dentro da div **#imagem** porém o que eu gostaria de fazer seria aparecer o valor da coluna "imagem" que é relacionado ao valor "nomeProduto" dentro da div #imagem e não o valor da coluna "nomeProduto".

Como posso proceder? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar `$.map`, use `$.each` para iterar o JSON retornado, criando um array com os nomes dos produtos e populando um objeto com uma chave relacionada ao nome da imagem, por exemplo:

```
{
   "Tenis Nike": "001"
}
```

Para isso crie os dois objetos dentro da função `.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var nomes = []; // cria a array
   var lista = {}; // cria o objeto
   ...
```

No `success` você usa o `$.each` para popular os dois objetos criados acima:

```
success:function(data){
   $.each(data, function(idx, item){
      // verifica se já consta na array e insere
      if(!~nomes.indexOf(item.nomeProduto)) nomes.push(item.nomeProduto);
      lista[item.nomeProduto] = item.imagem;
   });
   return result(nomes);
}
```

No `afterSelect` você puxa do objeto `lista` o valor da chave que contém o nome do produto, que corresponde ao valor da imagem:

```
afterSelect: function (data) {
   $('#imagem').html(lista[data]);
},
```

Comment: Olá Sam. Obrigado pelo seu retorno. Adaptei a sua solução e no console do Google Chrome obtive a seguinte resposta: `bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined at Typeahead.matcher (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1) at bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1 at Function.grep (jquery.min.js:2)  at Typeahead.process (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1) at e (jquery.min.js:2) at Object.success (index.php:50) at i (jquery.min.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2) at A (jquery.min.js:4) at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: Você acha que pode ser algum conflito com o cdn do plugin TypeAhead? De qualquer forma agradeço a sua atenção :)

Comment: Faz o seguinte: comenta a linha `dataType:"json",` e coloca no início da function do success um `console.log(data);`... deve dar um erro mas deve mostrar também um JSON... cola aqui o JSON que retorna

Comment: faz digita um nome no input pra retornar

Comment: Ok, obrigado. O console informou assim: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in ["Tenis Nike","01"]
    at w (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (index.php:46)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: antes não mostrou o JSON?

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe. No caso antes desse erro aparece esta linha de código: `["Tênis Nike","01"]`e em seguida aparece o erro acima abaixo do JSON. Seria isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103275/discussion-between-sam-and-michel-xavier).

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Sam. Adaptei a sua solução corrigindo o php script para enviar os resultados em JSON. dessa forma deu certo: `{$data[] = $row; } header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
 echo json_encode($data);
 exit();`